# Lighthouse Accessibility: axe-core Error: Cannot resolve id references for non-DOM node

Tags: html, accessibility, lighthouse

Lighthouse reports indicates errors for Accessibility for my website https://www.workarena.nl/.

[aria-*] attributes match their roles Error!

and

Elements with visible text labels have matching accessible names. Error! -> axe-core Error: `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded` - feature unsupported in your environment. Skipping label-content-name-mismatch rule.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Swy8o.png)

I have tried adjusting the area-labeledby with unique ids of the sections.

Comment: When I run Lighthouse or axe, I don't get those errors on your website. I get "parent" errors, which are false positives.

Comment: @slugolicious Are they false positives? Looking at the DOM the elements flagged as missing required parent are `button[role=tab]` whose parent is a heading: `div[role=tablist] > div > h3 > button[role=tab]`

Comment: @StevenLambert, yes, false positives.  Tabs and tablists say they must have "owners" of the correct type. They don't say they must have **immediate** parent.  *"Authors MUST ensure elements with role tab are contained in, or owned by, an element with the role tablist."*. https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#tab. Many scanning tools erroneously flag it as an error if the *immediate* parent (or child) isn't tab related.